Why is my Flink Tumbling window's checkpointed data size keeps growing
I have a Flink pipeline with RMQ source, some filters, enrichers ,keyby, aggregator ,Tumbling window(of 2sec,no watermark strategy is used. Processing time is used for windows trigger) and then RMQ sink. Increametal checkpoints is enabled with rocks DB as state backend.
Over the period of time, i see that my checkpoint size is increasing(>50MB). Even if compaction runs only significant amount of checkpoint size is reducing ie just 3 to 5MB(checkpoint size is still greater than 45MB).
I observed from flink webUI that its my tumbling window which keeps lot of check pointed data. After the window ends, i want my window operator to clean up the state and check pointed size in UI to return to 0(I understand that tumbling windows clears the state automatically after the window ends ).  But that is not happening. Why?
I am not able to configure stateTTLs as it is not a rich Fuction. Now how can i clear the checkpoint size of the window operator.
following is my checkpoint configurations
execution.checkpointing.checkpoints-after-tasks-finish.enabled: true
execution.checkpointing.interval: 10000
execution.checkpointing.externalized-checkpoint-retention: RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION
execution.checkpointing.max-concurrent-checkpoints: 1
execution.checkpointing.min-pause: 5000
execution.checkpointing.mode: EXACTLY_ONCE
execution.checkpointing.timeout: 60000

My window is cofigured for 2sec but checking interval is 10s. That means it includes 5 windows data?. is there any relation between them?
I am kind of stuck, any help will really be appreciated.
Can i trigger compaction often to get it cleared? If yes, how to do that in Tumbling Window or in aggregator funtion.
